# How to replace/transition a Kafka consumer group?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a repository with multiple Kafka streams. I want to extract one of the streams into its own repository. However, I'm not sure how to handle the consumer group of that stream. Here's what I mean: in the new repository the stream will have a different `application.id`. As far as I understand, the name of the consumer group is based on the `application.id` setting. If I simply turn off the old stream, for each partition of each topic the new stream will start from the zeroth offset instead from the offset, where the old stream has left off. This would lead to duplicate messages in the output topics.

Is there some general rule/best practice on how to handle this? Do I need to:

- turn off the old stream;
- check the old stream's consumer group's offset for each partition of each topic;
- "tell" the new stream to start from the respective offset. How do I "tell" :) it? I mean - if I use `kafka-console-consumer`, there are the `partition` and `offset` options, but the stream starts its own consumer behind the scene, so I'm not sure how to control it.

The stream uses quite a few input topics (around 20, luckly each topic has a single partition), so I'm not sure how exactly to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(0) If possible, I would recommend to try to preserve the `application.id` and all your problems go away. For this case, you can either first stop the old app and than start the new app, or even first spin up all new instances and afterward tear down all old instances. As both old and new app connect to the same Kafka cluster there will be a seamless switch.

(1) What you want to do only works if your Kafka Streams application is stateless; for a stateful application, more steps would be required to carry over the state to the new application instances. Or the new instances will just start with empty state (what might also be ok, depending on your application requirements).

(2) You will first need to stop all old application instances and receive the last committed offset for each input topic partition for the old `application.id` (via `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` using `--describe --group` options) Afterwards, you need to commit those offset using the new `application.id` (again, you can use `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` using option `--to-offset`). (For details cf https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-122%3A+Add+Reset+Consumer+Group+Offsets+tooling) Afterwards, you can start the new application instances that will pick up the committed offsets for the new `application.id`.